# Difference a variable between two dates

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use dplyr in R to difference a variable between two dates.

An simplified example:

```
# Simple script to test calculating the difference of a column between two dates
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tibble)

dataA <- as.tibble(ymd('2020-01-01') + days(seq(0:45)))
colnames(dataA) = c('date')
dataA <- dataA %>% mutate(xvar = seq(0:45))

#add the difference in xvar between two dates
dataA <- dataA %>% mutate(startd = date, endd=date+days(3))

dataA <- dataA %>% group_by(date) %>% 
         filter(date >= startd & date <= endd) %>% mutate(vardiff = last(xvar)-first(xvar))
```

I've tried a number of different possibilities for this last statement but can't get the calculation I'm looking for.  What I'm trying to achieve is the difference in xvar between January 5th and January 2nd and so on for the entire time series.   How can this be achieved using dplyr statements?

Thanks!

Comment: `dataA %>% mutate(vardiff = endd - startd)` ?

Comment: You may try `difftime` `dataA %>% mutate(vardiff = difftime(endd, startd, units = 'day'))`

Comment: For these two suggestions,  these are calculating the difference in time between the dates.   I seek to calculate the difference in the variable "xvar" that occurred on those specific dates.

Comment: @JFD can you show expected output for few rows

Comment: @JF Your group by 'date' have only one row per group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `match` to get index of `startd` and `endd` to get corresponding `xvar` and subtract them:

```
library(dplyr)
dataA %>%
  mutate(vardiff = xvar[match(endd, date)] - xvar[match(startd, date)])
```

This can also be written in base R using `transform` :

```
transform(dataA, vardiff = xvar[match(endd, date)] - xvar[match(startd, date)])
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak!  This is the solution I used.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `findInterval` and this should also work when there are no exact matches

```
library(dplyr)
dataA %>% 
    mutate(vardiff = xvar[findInterval(endd, date)] - 
        xvar[findInterval(startd, date)])
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
transform(dataA, vardiff = xvar[findInterval(endd, date)] - 
        xvar[findInterval(startd, date)])
```